# AWS policy to limit S3 data size per IAM user

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, amazon-iam

I am trying to put a restriction on **how much** data a given user can upload to an S3 bucket based on account tiers.

For example:
Tier 1: user can upload max 1GB to S3 |
Tier 2: “” 5GB |
Tier 3: “” 25GB |
etc.

I have not been able to find any resources on the web attacking this issue.

I have explored the world of IAM and S3 bucket policies, but, to my understanding, it looks like everything is concerned with restricting access to the buckets as opposed to limiting the amount of data a user can contribute.

I still want the user to be able execute CRUD operations against this bucket, but only while remaining within the size limit associated with their tier.

All suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: How do you define a "user"? Is it an IAM User or a user of your application?

Answer (score 3):

There is **no in-built capability** in Amazon S3 to limit the amount of storage.

One method you could use is to **have your application monitor the amount of storage consumed by a user**. When they want to upload another file, you can check whether their limit has been exceeded. If so, then do not permit the upload.

If their limit has *not* been exceeded, your application can **create a pre-signed URL** for uploading a file and, within the policy for that pre-signed URL, specify a maximum file size permitted. Your application would set this size based upon the amount left within their quota.

Please note that all logic regarding the quota will be the **responsibility of your application**.

See: [Uploading Objects Using Presigned URLs - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html)

Comment: The link to the presigned URLs is about uploading with PUT. From what I understand it is not possible to attach a policy restricting the max file size with those. Only the browser based POST presigned URLs allow attaching a policy. See [Creating a POST Policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-HTTPPOSTConstructPolicy.html).